# flash 1093 syntax error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I am a complete noob when it comes to flash. I subscribe to adobe to I installed adobe animate.

I inherited a project that contained a flash swf file. I got the source too thank God. The problem when I open it it says there are many errors after upgrading to actionscript 3.0.  I've screenshoted the errors.

I don't know what this is wanting me to change. I changed some of the errors that were coding problems but these I can't find anything on.

[syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW7Df.jpg)

[syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK3Sb.jpg)

Comment: Sorry to tell you this but AS2 and AS3 and similar in name only. If you know both languages you could rebuild the first one into the AS3 version but if you don't know either language then you really have your work cut out for you. It's like trying to translate a German text into a Spanish text when all you speak is English. Learn the languages first.

Comment: If it's not possible to easily fix these 2 repeating errors then can you recommend a company I can hire to fix this for me?

Comment: I don't know of one but I think you can post jobs here on stack exchange. Maybe search a question StackOverflow Meta site to try to find where to post jobs.